# How to set DayNight theme for BottomSheetDialog

Tags: android, material-design, android-bottomsheetdialog, theme-daynight

I'm migrating to the new android [DayNight theme](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme).

I've replaced `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark(Light).ActionBar` to `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.DayNight.ActionBar`

`ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark(Light)` to `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.DayNight`

Everything looks fine. Except that I cannot do the same with BottomSheetDialog. Does DayNight theme exist for BottomSheetDialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, try to use `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.BottomSheetDialog`. For some reason code completion isn't working in Android Studio for that case.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.BottomSheetDialog</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the Material Components library you have to use a [Material Components Theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

If you can't use it, you should use a [Bridge theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#bridge-themes-bridge-themes) in your app:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge">
```